# Evaluation of Nested Conditional Type - Resulting Types Not Behaving as Expected

Tags: typescript, types

I have a type which represents a payload from an API call. If a foreign-key is defined on the payload, the payload is known to also contain metadata corresponding to the related record:

```js
type Payload = {
  id: number
  districtAdmin?: string | null
  // added after request for more info
  dedicatedSupport?: string | null
  edges: {
    // if typeof districtAdmin === "string"
    districtAdmin: {
        name: string
    }
    // else
    districtAdmin: never
    // same with dedicatedSupport
  }
}
```

This [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgEQIbFQBVSANge1QBMoBeKAbwFgAoKeqASyIC4o5hFGA7Ac1oZQArgkTdUAWwhsOXPrQC+tWqEhQA8ol6pujAF7pG+btjyEiAHgFQAKgCUoEAB7AI3InHacevKAB8obiFcXDIvOV8AoJCAGloAPjDqOiZWQKEJACMkayJGWUYAY2AAQSIJHgB+NntrCCJeCDg2ZME8guKyiu5q2wdnV3dPAr4oSthRNAxTAmIoNm4IADcclKUadeUaQuMOKCJUeCQ2I5R0LBxZknJWhmY2ACIDh7iU+hEkcSlHg4A6TPwmQeii2O24ewOml4bChOn0hmMM3MSWs9HuUAAjK82vlvJ1yjwfqgXqjHA0mi1STiOqUCdw2AdTqT1pttrt8LgIL8CLwABSQrS-eqNOC-dp42ndX4fMSSCAASlBu2AgXwaChMK0cIMwCMJkuyJupPRACZsQxxVx8d0FsFcOb6MKKZRBCyleCOVyebzuGrUFCheTRZaipKeNLRF8FVt3XsPsgSmEALLoAAWv0QOiI+AkvPlUESAAZfgBWWhgvaZ9w5qEot6pNjxxPjDHzKBm0kh62E4QIBNjKBPYlt6L20lO5qUKkW3FWsP03sQfvjRmiNtCdwQABmPHqzJBNHL7M53PwfKr2YkAYnYtnoa6VQjnzlipojC3UF5F5rgq78-ztz0BWnqnueWY-rwgYireNIPtwT6ylIr4KEAA) is my attempt to implement this type (which only attempts to handle one relationship right now):

```js
type UserDataPayload = {
    id: string
    username: string
}

type OrganizationPayload<
  TR extends string | null = string | null,
> = {
  id: number
  districtAdmin?: TR
  edges: {
    districtAdmin?: TR extends string ? UserDataPayload : never
  }
}


const daUser: UserDataPayload = {
    id: "da",
    username: "da.bob"
}

const daOrg: OrganizationPayload = {
    id: 1,
    districtAdmin: "da",
    edges: {
        districtAdmin: daUser
    }
}
// (property) districtAdmin?: UserDataPayload | undefined
// Object is possibly 'undefined'.(2532)
console.log(daOrg.edges.districtAdmin.username)
```

Comment: Conditional types are not the right tool for this job.  Looks like you just want a union like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAQoXm).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz the shown type is actually a bit simplified, but I understand the concept. Let me just implement it fully really quick and make sure.

Comment: @jcalz the problem is that there are multiple related records, and each new included foreignKey would result in a doubling of the number of types to include in the union, which is not practical. E.g. there's not just an optional districtAdmin, there's also an optional designatedSupportUser.

Comment: If that matters you should probably [edit] the question to show a more illustrative example.  There are ways of generating unions programmatically, which makes these things more practical than you might be envisioning.

Comment: @jcalz generating the types is not going to happen at the moment. I would like to be able to do conditional types if possible (or some other approach that does not require 2^n unions).

Comment: But this looks very much like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  Conditional types are not the right tool for the stated job.  If you asked me how to use a chainsaw to open a can of soup, I'd be remiss if I tried to figure out some way to get that to happen instead of directing you to a can opener.  Would you like an answer that just says "no, this is not possible"?

Comment: I see you edited the previous comment to talk about 2^n unions.  Maybe you'd be okay if we moved away from a specific type and instead gave you a helper function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WkKLLW)?

Comment: Curious why conditional types are not the tool for the job? What the edges include is conditioned upon the types of the foreign key fields. What would you consider to be a use case for conditional types? This helper type does look like it works, but it looks more verbose and harder to read and understand than the approach I was going for. Fundamentally, I don't understand why my approach doesn't work, or why this problem isn't a good candidate.

If it's not possible, that would be good to know. My problem probably primarily stems from a lack of understanding of how the type system works.

Comment: Ultimately, this will be part of a set of types that define the API boundary for my application. The goal is to define them as simply and declaratively as the type system allows while making impossible payloads impossible to represent. The consumer (me and others) should need to know very little about the underlying payload types.

Comment: I’m on mobile now and I won’t get back to a real computer for a number of hours.  If you’re more concerned with why conditional types don’t work directly I can write up an answer explaining that (when I return), but then I probably won’t go into an alternative approach, since it sounds like you’re not really looking for that.  Acceptable?

Comment: @jcalz That sounds great. An alternate solution would be fine, but it needs to live entirely within the type system and not depend on the consumer remembering to use a function. I'm sure that typescript's type system is sophisticated enough to represent the type I'm asking for. Regardless, thank you for your time and thoughtful responses.

Comment: Here's a sketch... you might be able to represent your requirements via a *generic* conditional type, like `type OrganizationalPayload<T> =`, but when you create a value of that type it will be some *specific* value.  TypeScript doesn't have *existentially quantified generics* so you can't say `const daOrg: OrganizationalPayload<∃T> = ...` where `∃T` means "some `T` I don't want to specify".  Your attempt at making `T` have a *default* of, say, `string | null`, doesn't have the effect you want. ...

Comment: ... what it does is produce a single specific type where `T` is a union, and the conditional type is fully evaluated. It's not really conditional anymore.  Often the way people proceed here is to make a generic helper function (as I've shown) but you don't want to do that. The other way to proceed, if possible, is to make a big union, if there are a finite number of `T` types that would fit as the type argument of your generic type.  You don't want to do that either. So I think we're stuck and what you want to do is not possible, unless you're willing to widen the scope of potential solutions.

Comment: Does that seem to cover everything or am I missing something?  The actual answer will be more detailed, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: That all makes sense. So my type should theoretically work if I'm willing to pick either null or string, but not if I use a union, because the union doesn't mean it's an unspecified type. Basically what I am trying to make is a type that isn't really known until the contents are inspected narrowing the types down, but conditional types don't do that, union types do. I must say I find it surprising that the language doesn't have a more ergonomic way to accomplish this than by manually crafting unions, but I understand you answer, and will accept it if you submit it. No further code necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) you've got here,

```
type OrganizationPayload<TR extends string | null = string | null> = {
  id: number
  districtAdmin?: TR
  edges: {
    districtAdmin?: TR extends string ? UserDataPayload : never
  }
}
```

is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), and therefore depends on a type parameter `TR` in order to specify whether the `districtAdmin` property is either present in both the top level object and the `edges` subproperty (by specifying `string` as `TR`), or absent in both places (by specifying `null` as `TR`).

---

Well, that seems to be the *intent*, anyway.  That property is [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) no matter what, even if you specify `string` as `TR`:

```
type OPS = OrganizationPayload<string>;
/* type OPS = {
  id: number;
  districtAdmin?: string | undefined;
  edges: {
      districtAdmin?: UserDataPayload | undefined;
  };
 } */
```

So maybe the type should actually be

```
type OrganizationPayload<TR extends string | null = string | null> = (
  TR extends string ? { districtAdmin: string } : { districtAdmin?: null }
) & {
  id: number;
  edges: (
    TR extends string ? { districtAdmin: UserDataPayload } :
    { districtAdmin?: never }
  )
};
```

Which now results in

```
type OPS = OrganizationPayload<string>;
/* type OPS = {
    districtAdmin: string;
} & {
    id: number;
    edges: {
        districtAdmin: UserDataPayload;
    };
} */

type OPN = OrganizationPayload<null>;
/* type OPN = {
    districtAdmin?: null | undefined;
} & {
    id: number;
    edges: {
        districtAdmin?: undefined;
    };
} */
```

which is equivalent to what you're trying to express, I think.

---

But then you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) a variable as being just type `OrganizationalPayload` with no type argument:

```
const daOrg: OrganizationPayload = { ... }
```

Perhaps your intent there is that the compiler should look at the initializing value and *infer* the most appropriate argument for `TR`.  That's not what happens.

Your definition of `OrganizationalPayload` gives `TR` a [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) of the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `string | null`.  When you leave out the type argument, the compiler just uses that default:

```
// const daOrg: OrganizationPayload<string | null>
```

And *that* type evaluates to

```
type OP = OrganizationPayload;
/* type OP = ({
    districtAdmin: string;
} | {
    districtAdmin?: null | undefined;
}) & {
    id: number;
    edges: {
        districtAdmin: UserDataPayload;
    } | {
        districtAdmin?: undefined;
    };
} */
```

which is a type where both properties are optional no matter what, and the presence of `districtAdmin` at the top level doesn't imply that it will be present in `edges`.  Oops.

And when you assign that initializing value to the variable, the compiler does not keep track of the particular value that was inside the `edges` property.  The part of `OrganizationPayload` where `edges` is specified is not itself a union type, so there is no [narrowing upon assignment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments).  So you get the error:

```
console.log(daOrg.edges.districtAdmin.username) // error!
// -------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

---

Again, there is no direct way to ask the compiler to infer `TR` from the initializing value.  There's a suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#32794](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32794) to support this, and if this is ever implemented it might look like

```
const daOrg: OrganizationPayload<infer> = { ... }
```

But for now it's not part of the language.  Often in cases like this people write generic helper functions to infer the type parameter, like

```
const asOrgPayload = <TR,>(op: OrganizationalPayload<TR>) => op;
const daOrg = asOrgPayload({ ... });
```

but you're not interested in this sort of approach.  And even if you were it would probably need to be modified to get inference to work, since inferring *from* a conditional type is tricky.

---

Perhaps `OrganizationalPayload<string | null>` evaluates to the wrong type, since it allows "cross-correlated" terms.  Since `OrganizationalPayload<string>` is fine, and `OrganizationalPayload<null>` is fine, maybe you want `OrganizationalPayload<string | null>` to evaluate to the union of them.

If so, you could again modify `OrganizationalPayload` to be a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```
type OrganizationPayload<TR extends string | null = string | null> =
  TR extends unknown ? ((
    TR extends string ? { districtAdmin: string } : { districtAdmin?: null }
  ) & {
    id: number;
    edges: (
      TR extends string ? { districtAdmin: UserDataPayload } :
      { districtAdmin?: never }
    )
  }) : never;
```

And now `OrganizationalPayload` evaluates to the proper (albeit ugly) type:

```
type OP = OrganizationPayload;
/* type OP = (
  { districtAdmin: string; } & 
  { id: number;  edges: { districtAdmin: UserDataPayload; }; }
) | (
  { districtAdmin?: null | undefined; } & 
  { id: number; edges: { districtAdmin?: undefined; }; }
) */
```

And narrowing upon assignment happens correctly now, and everything behaves wonderfully!

```
const daOrg: OrganizationPayload = {
  id: 1,
  districtAdmin: "da",
  edges: { districtAdmin: daUser }
}
console.log(daOrg.edges.districtAdmin.username) // okay
```

---

Of course that `OrganizationPayload` definition is now fairly ugly with three conditional types in it.  They can be rearranged to have just a single conditional type that is equivalent:

```
type OrganizationPayload<TR extends string | null = string | null> =
  { id: number } & (
    TR extends string ?
    { districtAdmin: string; edges: { districtAdmin: UserDataPayload } } :
    { districtAdmin?: null; edges: { districtAdmin?: never } }
  );
```

Or possibly even just:

```
type OrganizationPayload<TR extends string | null = string | null> =
  TR extends string ?
  { id: number; districtAdmin: string; edges: { districtAdmin: UserDataPayload } } :
  { id: number; districtAdmin?: null; edges: { districtAdmin?: never } };
```

Which becomes, if you don't specify `TR`:

```
type OP = OrganizationPayload;
/* type OP = 
  { id: number; districtAdmin: string; edges: { districtAdmin: UserDataPayload; }; } | 
  { id: number; districtAdmin?: null; edges: { districtAdmin?: never; };     
*/
```

A plain union type.

That implies that conditional types, while possibly useful to the typings developer so they don't have to repeat things, really aren't what's useful to the users of the type... *unions* are the supported method to do the kind of narrowing you're expecting.

But you're not interested in that sort of approach either.  Unions are a no-go for you, presumably because your type will end up with some large power of two of union members if you write that (like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBRabN)).

---

So at this point I'd say I'm stuck.  Conditional types don't, in and of themselves, give you the behavior you're looking for.  You'd need to either use a generic helper function or a union for inference and/or assignment narrowing.  Or some other possible approach (I didn't get into [existentially quantified generic types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types) here because they're not directly part of the language and even if they were you wouldn't get the narrowing you're apparently looking for.)

Hopefully at least you understand why the current approach doesn't work.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBFJIAuAnjMgKpQQBOAIiGSAAogUYD2IAJkgC8eEqSQBLfgC4kUMgwnAA5mNIBXeg1CRZ8xSrEBfImJ3Q4iJAHlFy0cULjyVZLeUhgErKwk9gnNx8-AA8auIAKgBKSBAAHmQQwPxQcgpK9gA+SMDqGBjCaQZZOXkYADThAHyFBE7OkjKlYABGjOGk-BL6EvBkAIL8YEoA-LLRHbH8ytCydQ3iXT19g8PAY0jRsQlJKUUZSCNIdIwsbIG8AkiywBAAbu31ziZPSC-OlNQ27ADKhe6eby+fwXYIhHoqKoAbnCAHoAFQuL7WX61SZSG7qVqMGGvTrddIrIajPTpFRIbLqZIQABmSgg-FxCwZMygc0mziWhIGxPWshOzFYHC4l0ElOpdNujMmRiZzyQ8NhpnqLzM4AsCGQ7AYPGoDGsMDIflABTq4U+bgYHi8PiNIJFYK28USyVSEJKuXyhXdFNK+RqIgAFJMnTtXftyUdcEguYoiWtScU3tc8DGCXGeWsNp6Cu9xABKJAAMgcCwxzTaDDlzhZsyQwbxkRizt2brJ9ijaeWmaU-K0Z2FQSuRmuHNTsd6Pb5OXujDek3z4Vlyo+rm+fxEAJtwICDoE4Pb0LhiIt67Rjfx3dWvYjymryZL8wWjUx2KrY9rbNLz856cn1+APtTiFUEBHvZ57xHRUV3EU8UQAOX+K1AVtY1QNCHMj1eBEkTcdhEJEJ8FgneMST9ApxX4Wl6WlV4R0fMdy1yN9wPET92QvBoSKnDYqSoyUGVY0hlzohUlUcVdkXYJDrSBO1dyHWjnBwuDpKDIiuL-UjANvSDfQ038r15bMyl9PjqKlSDCwYzimKxSshKmVkOJ-QzuQAoDBXOPclOfEdsgM59uIA3iJRoxyRPlaCJPEeB-HkGMQAFTyB3Q88yyaAAifgQEyypG00RhzFkbKQAAOhaHgWkypcYNIOLgASnL3FkLc5LQnz0oacsAEZ8uIrSpxKnK8smdjvwGoyE0SgUZVq7DYSQBqmpAFqbGQ7d5PQg8k2yTC6qW+KeAwCAyt4ZRA2aq0ys-Mrgt5MrCu0dVC1hRbGB1BgAEI4UWgBaAHAb+moAD8wfBiHIahiHfpsFoACsID6SRUhgHgoCgCQWgwCgkAAcnMgT+DxsqYNVRw1UgWBNSQJg-xaBxzTXNrUPtRSQlDF09h9PbTJEHnyIDENmzDPYqQAa2AHgAHdgEOesGx-TnW1veXo3u6afRHOYu3c4zMS9PNnGsibuqaZiHI-aY60V1zlfDH1Ow1m8BVSzrtbHUh1cGkKblnBh504xdGyMQs-Yed8YtIVSN3W2TWYU0UdoyLDlJPZnUUIsdnZ0909Jsn87JYq3nNNn8c5SkCfIivToqZqSCLjlCd22zD7xUjPG8Cy89azA2KKQQnwqXYsy-EIvLc48bu80qayKHyyx0i8QoPE+u8Jk5utur49cO+Qpbecb259z9soQfJBJmjCecVIafdYzDzjn7KvFPP2VA+N31D-EY-e7InMZkwqWQvlfF8FZb73xzqFfi4U3jv3CIWOurxlpkBmloSu3lFJdWcOWUqo0CpaGKkgUqFUqo1TogdVBiU1osxbp1LOjZer9Vnv-HS+CWE1mtl+P+j9eSyBygKT+K9wjLWOqdc6l1VrXVujnR6RCXpIDekgHg4suBk2VDBcw1MrA-AkGAGAJ0A5mleHBDa7U2ZJ3ttzdsvpAH81sbzf0wgwE3wDvResY5rFtiTCMMcvD-z8N0k5OsATtKYMHKKZMHtOJhJ4v3c+UCfb6xnBHaJC5cTrzPJucxCdtrulTuIDuUlY4zwrrpEeBdnxuMctPT2ixknTVdq-UUNcR7IMknhRudDt7szbrvVSXds6NIAaZSiFlBKVLHqQGpJdQn1J7nwvug9gGTM4svYSYkDqqU3ptDqb8BkZ1qOAi2t8PE-y9g-QJmsz4hJ4Vc8Jz9gJYNafA5M2QwHQISXcnWXzUlnPPogwFrwOmxXimgwRGCnleUicEHB48sojU4eIJ6xDSGVWqvNUR4KaFWlark+h2DGEZVkH1SY5SOFjW4b8kZOlIVziNsI+qR0TpnR4BdK6ygbrcLurS+RRVFHKNUeomK5MtHqh0cgAAwsdDAIAYD0EECYzpTc9mWMdCLLmPiDhOIKA43agsXGNm8arPxjZr7m3srfcpecfnjlpREtKI4YkLAta+ByDz4nkUSdS+1J9sz+2iZk0xGdY49P2UnAp7d04lPhW5JZN485TJnrMqevqZ7xuuS7F+LzghtNEqC6OnddkWMTmCfp2EY1dLjQ0-1-cgGwMXqJKpJKIGRx-HUzimbtIwImb5BYGzkyFr3iiEteSd6VpHWpS+5qTlWqrJ6p+tqkkn0ddXN5-kZ2urnSxRdKScw+tLnE32-yF0f2cOEYd1D6UMDXUSseeCkWTFReqYa5UMUUOeFQnFnL8Xx0JVE4lZtSXIsWVm9hT7GwrrYQIpKWgmUIbEayyRnLuWsl5Sfflz1ICvUWsKigGiKaECMEAA)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed, informative response. This isn't a problem I have to solve today, so I can mull over the options you've given here and let you know ultimately what I went with and why.